# Insert comma separated list created with HMENU in TEXT.value

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to insert my comma separated list created with HMENU at the value of the TEXT item. If I fill the list manually, all working fine, but I can't fill my value from the created hmenu:

```
temp.pageIds = HMENU
temp.pageIds.entryLevel = 2
temp.pageIds.1 = TMENU
temp.pageIds.1 {
  NO.stdWrap.field = uid
  NO.allWrap = |,
  NO.doNotLinkIt = 1
}

#output temp.pageIds for example 13,53,12,34,

temp.orderedContent = TEXT
temp.orderedContent {

  value < temp.pageIds # <------ not working (value = 23,25,57,... working)

  split {
    token = ,
    cObjNum = 1
    1 = COA
    1 {
      10 = CONTENT
      10 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
          pidInList.current = 1
          where = colPos = 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` property of a `TEXT` object will not be interpreted. If you just copy the `temp.pageIds`-object, it will be just be the literal string `HMENU` (and have some subproperties), which is not a list of page IDs.

To get it evaluated, notice in [the docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Text/Index.html) that the type of `value` is of type `string/stdWrap`, so the value will be filtered through the [`stdWrap`-function](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#stdwrap). stdWrap has the property [`cObject`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#stdwrap-cobject), which can be used to interpret content objects.

So this should work:

```
value.cObject < temp.pageIds
```